# What does it mean for a program to exclusively use a disk?

Tags: windows

Hi all [this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-SG/windows7/Improve-performance-by-defragmenting-your-hard-disk) has a message which goes like this:

> If the disk is already in exclusive use by another program or is formatted using a file system other than NTFS file system, FAT, or FAT32, it can't be defragmented.

I was wondering what does it mean for a disk to be in exclusive use by a program?

Answer (score 2):

They are some software that can manage directly a hard disk. For example, [Oracle Data Base Management System can work with raw devices](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b14207/storage.htm#BGBDBAHH).

Comment: How does a disk identify itself as being "exclusively used" by a program?

Answer (score 2):

Other disk management tools can obtain an exclusive lock on a particular drive.  For example, if you are using a third party or other Windows utility to defragment or repair a drive already, then Windows defrag utility would not be able to get the exclusive lock that it needs in order to defragment the drive.

Comment: right! take a look to [truecrypt troubleshooting](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=troubleshooting): "The operating system reports to TrueCrypt that the device is locked for an exclusive access by an application.Possible Solution: It usually helps to disable or uninstall the interfering application, which is usually an anti-virus utility, a disk management application, etc."